Hamiltonian graph on a $8\times 8$ chessboard with upper left corner and bottom right corner square removed
Suppose we are given the setup in the title. Two squares are adjacent if and only if they share a common edge. I want to find out whether the obtained graph considering squares as nodes would be Hamiltonian or not? I am out of ideas as to how to solve this? The degree condition that sum of every non adjacent node is greater than number of nodes doesn't hold, neither do I see any set of vertices which I can remove to get more components than the vertices in the removed set. Kindly help. Thank you!

Edges of the graph are adjacent squares?

@Aig no, two nodes are adjacent if they are adjacent squares

Consider the chessboard coloring. The squares in the Hamiltonian path must alternate colors.

@Aig And by adjacent, I mean any form of adjacency on the board, right left up or down, just not diagonally

Yes, that’s exactly what I wrote. I guess, the word “edge” has two meanings here: edge of the square and edge of the graph.

@Aig i am unable to see a Hamiltonian path or a cycle, since the two squares are removed.

Two removed squares are of the same color. Hence there are, say, $32$ black and $30$ white squares left. Let there be a Hamiltonian cycle. The color of squares alternates in this cycle, so there must be equally many black and white squares. Contradiction. So there is no Hamiltonian cycle.

oh ok got it! It essentially form $K_{m,n}$ where m and n are not equal! Thank you so much

@Sj2704 $K_{m,n}$ usually stands for complete bipartite graph. This is just a bipartite graph. But yes, this is the idea.

Oh yes my bad, thank you so much!
